# Ocultar una columna en función del valor de un ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5

gracias de antemano. Tengo un problema para ocultar una columna en cabecera de tabla. He probado diferentes opciones y no doy con la solución.

HTML:

```
<tr>
   <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn
          [pSortableColumn]="col.field"              
          [hidden]="col.id">
           <span>{{col.header}}</span>
          <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>              
        </th> 
      </tr>
```

El problema me viene del: [hidden]="col.id"

En el TS tengo una serie de variables:

```
Pais: boolean;

Fecha: boolean;
```

y están inicializadas:

```
this.Pais = false;

this.Fecha = false;
```

Lo que quiero es que el valor del atributo hidden que le pongo, que viene de un ngFor corresponda con el nombre de variable que tengo declarada en el TS

¿Se puede hacer así? ¿Tengo plantear este problema desde otro enfoque?

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `*ngIf` ?, es más correcto y puede que arregle tus problemas.

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres hacer: ¿mostrar o no ciertas columnas según el valor de un atributo del componente?